# eBay API returning errorID 2000, Service operation GetItem is unknown

Tags: python, ebay-api

I am trying to send a request to the eBay API using the GetItem call, but I keep getting errorID 2000,

```
ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: 'GetItem: Internal Server Error, Domain: CoreRuntime, Severity: Error, errorId: 2000, Service operation GetItem is unknown'
```

which does not exist when looking on the API page that has the list of possible [errors](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/Errors/ErrorMessages.htm#ErrorsByNumber) by number

I am trying to use the [GetItem](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getitem.html) call, but it seems that the eBay API can not recognise it. After some reasearch I found that there is another call I could try, which is the [GetSingleItem](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/getsingleitem.html), but that does not seem to be recognised by the API either.

This is the code that I am using:

```
api_requests = {"ItemID": item_id}
response_get_item = api.execute("GetItem", api_requests)
```

Where the variable item_id is a normal 12 character string of numbers that do actually correspond to an item on eBay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had forgot to import the "Connection" from ebaysdk.shopping and I was using the "Connection" from ebaysdk.finding from the previous bit of code.

Old import statement:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
```

New import statements:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
from ebaysdk.shopping import Connection as shopping
```